# Работа с DOM JS

Tags: javascript

Как известно, работать с DOM можно по событию DOMContentLoaded элемента document, не дожидаясь события window.onload. Но так же есть событие document.onreadystatechange, которое при первой генерации говорит о том, что структура DOM готова (document.readyState при этом == interactive). document.readyState == interactive мы получаем немного раньше события DOMContentLoaded, вопрос почему? Что именно ещё не подгрузилось между первой генерацией document.onreadystatechange и событием DOMContentLoaded? На скрине видно время с начала загрузки страницы и события.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Весьма занятный вопрос. Я заинтересовался и немного углубился в тему. Возможно, я нашел правильный ответ. Позже обязательно проведу "опыты" для подтверждения, а пока предварительные данные)

Вот [на этой странице](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded#domcontentloaded-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%8B) подробное (в отличие от сухой и формальной офф. документации) описание принципа работы события `DOMContentLoaded`. Если подробно ознакомиться, можно заметить упоминания того, что событие, все же, ожидает загрузки некоторых стилей, к примеру, в случае, если они блокируют выполнение внутри `<script>` на странице.

По всей видимости, это и отличает `DOMContentLoaded` от `Document.readyState == interactive`, который, судя по всему, вызывается непосредственно после окончания парсинга страницы.

Эти выводы подтверждаются ответом на этот схожий вопрос:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665561/document-readystate-of-interactive-vs-ondomcontentloaded

Вкратце перевод ответа:

После окончания парсинга документа браузер выполняет следующие шаги:

1. Устанавливает статус готовности документа в "**interactive**".
2. Убирает все узлы (ноды) из стека открытых элементов.
3. *(самое интереное)* Если список скриптов, которые будут выполнены после окончания парсинга документа, не пуст, выполняет следующие действия: ожидает готовности к выполнению первого из скриптов и отсутствия блокирующих его таблиц стилей, после чего выполняет его; ожидает готовности к выполнению второго из скриптов и отсутствию... и так, пока не будут выполнены все скрипты, ожидавшие выполнения после окончания парсинга документа.
4. Помещает в очередь вызова простое "пузырьковое" событие **DOMContentLoaded**.

Comment: По всей видимости так и есть, DOMContentLoaded ждет ещё и загрузку скриптов, а onreadystatechange - нет. Так что надежнее работать с DOM по событию DOMContentLoaded, так как могут быть какие-то предварительные манипуляции в загружаемых скриптах.